# Sometimes ng-click don't work in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new IONIC & AngularJS. Currently, working on an app & stuck at a point. Don't how to resolve the issue.

I've a login form. After user login to the app, he/she will land at HOME page. In the home page, I've an image. On that image, i'm using ng-click. So, on click of that image, it'll redirect the user to some other page. Here I'm facing the issue & the issue is just after login when I'm coming to the home page, on click of that image ng-click is not working at all. But, once I refresh the browser & click on that image ng-click start working. Don't know why this wired thing is happening.

Here are all files which I'm using. The ionic version which I'm using in 1.7.12

app.js

```
(function(){

    var app = angular.module('e2pro', ['ionic', 'e2pro.LoginController', 'e2pro.HomeController', 'e2pro.AttendanceController', 'e2pro.LogoutController','e2pro.MenuController','e2pro.EmpProfileController','e2pro.EmpSearchController', 'e2pro.VendorController', 'ngMessages', 'ngCordova', 'angularMoment']);

    var requestToken    = "";
    var accessToken     = "";
    var deviceToken     = null;
    var access_token    = null;
    var refresh_token   = null;
    var session_id      = null;
    var user_id         = null;
    var user_login_type = null;
    var route_to        = null;

    app.run(function($ionicPlatform, RequestsService, GeoAlert) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
            // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
            // for form inputs)
            if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
                cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
                cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
            }
            if (window.StatusBar) {
                // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
                StatusBar.styleDefault();
            }

            console.log('inside app.run function');
        });

    });


    // Service for logout user from app
    app.factory("User", function($http, $q, $rootScope, $ionicHistory, $state) {
        return {
            logout: function(){
                window.localStorage.clear();
                $ionicHistory.clearCache();
                $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
                $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({ disableBack: true, historyRoot: true });

                $state.go("login");
            }
        }
    });


    app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {
        $stateProvider

        .state('app', {
            url: '/app',
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
            controller: 'MenuController'
        })

        .state('app.tabs', {
            url: "/tabs",
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html",
                }
            }
        })

        .state('login', {
            url: "/login",
            templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
            //controller: 'LoginController'
        })

        .state('markEmpAttendance', {
            url: "/markEmpAttendance",
            templateUrl: "templates/attendance/markEmpAttendance.html",
            //controller: 'AttendanceController'
        })

        .state('app.tabs.home', {
            url: '/home',
            views: {
                'home-tab': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
                }
            }
        })

        .state('app.tabs.emp-profile', {
            url: '/emp-profile/:empId',
            views: {
                'home-tab': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/empProfile.html',
                    //controller: 'EmpProfileController'
                }
            }
        })

        .state('app.tabs.vendor', {
            url: '/vendor',
            views: {
                'home-tab': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/vendor/vendor.html',
                    //controller: 'EmpProfileController'
                }
            }
        })

        .state('app.tabs.emp-search', {
            url: '/emp-search',
            views: {
                'home-tab': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/empSearch.html',
                    //controller: 'EmpProfileController'
                }
            }
        })

        .state('app.tabs.service-request', {
            url: "/articles",
            views: {
                'serviceRequest-tab': {
                    templateUrl: "templates/serviceRequest.html",
                    controller: 'articlesCtrl'
                }
            }
        })

        .state('app.tabs.colonies', {
            url: "/colonies",
            views: {
                'colonies-tab': {
                    templateUrl: "templates/colonies.html",
                    controller: 'coloniesCtrl'
                }
            }
        })

        .state('app.foo', {
            url: "/foo",
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: "templates/foo.html",
                    controller: 'fooCtrl'
                }
            }
        });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/tabs/home');
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('sessionInjector');
    });

}());
```

login.js (controller file)

```
angular.module('e2pro.LoginController', [])

// Employee Attendance Controller
.controller('LoginController', function($http, $scope, $state, $ionicHistory, $ionicLoading, $cordovaOauth, RequestsService){
    console.log('Inside Login Controller');

    var baseUrl=null;

    $scope.credentials = {};
    $scope.validationFailed = false;

    $http.get('js/config.json')
            .then(function(res){
                baseUrl = res.data.server[res.data.mode];
            });


    // Method for user's default login
    $scope.validateCredentials = function(form){
        console.log('Form Validation start for login : '+form.$valid);
        var attendance_require = null;
        var emp_attendance_status = null;

        // Setting module data element for the api request
        $scope.credentials.module = 'user_login';
        $scope.credentials.pageId = 1548;

        // Check form validation status & move control accordingly
        if(!form.$valid)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Show spinner animation
        $ionicLoading.show({
            template: '<ion-spinner icon="android"></ion-spinner>'
        });

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: baseUrl+'/S/E2Pro_MobileApiEndPoint.php',
            data : $scope.credentials
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                if(response['data']['status'] === 'success')
                {
                    session_id    = response['data']['data']['session_id'];
                    user_id       = response['data']['data']['user_id'];
                    route_to      = response['data']['data']['route_to'];
                    attendance_require = response['data']['data']['attendance_require'];
                    emp_attendance_status = response['data']['data']['emp_attendance_status'];

                    window.localStorage.setItem("session_id", session_id);
                    window.localStorage.setItem("user_id", user_id);
                    window.localStorage.setItem("user_login_type", 'default');

                    // Hide Spinner before redirecting to home page
                    $ionicLoading.hide();

                    // Redirecting to home page
                    if(route_to === 'home'){
                        $state.go('app.tabs.home');
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // Hide Spinner before redirecting to home page
                    $ionicLoading.hide();

                    // Show message for email id & password miss match
                    $scope.validationFailed = true;
                }

            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                // console.log('Error occcur during user authentication');

                // Hide Spinner before redirecting to home page
                $ionicLoading.hide();
            });
    };

});
```

Home.js (Controller file)

```
angular.module('e2pro.HomeController', [])

// Employee Attendance Controller
.controller('HomeController', function($scope, $state, $location, $ionicHistory, $ionicSideMenuDelegate, $http, $ionicPopup, User, GeoAlert){

    console.log('Inside Home Controller');
    var baseUrl=null;

    // Check application session. If it's found not exist redirect user to login page
    if(window.localStorage.getItem("session_id") === "undefined" || window.localStorage.getItem("session_id") === null) {
        $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
            disableAnimate: true,
            disableBack: true
        });

        $state.go("login");
        return false;
    }

    $scope.empName               = '';
    $scope.alertMsgBox           = false;
    $scope.alertMsgText          = '';
    $scope.employees             = [];

    $http.get('js/config.json')
            .then(function(res){
                baseUrl = res.data.server[res.data.mode];
            });

    // Method for showing Vendor page
    $scope.showVendorPage = function(){
        console.log('Clicked on vendor icon');
        $state.go('app.tabs.vendor');
    }

});
```

Home.html (template file)

```
<ion-view view-title="Home">
    <ion-content class="has-tabs">

        <div ng-controller='HomeController' >
            <div class="row" style="margin-top:15px;">
                <div class="col">
                    <img src="img/leave.png" ng-click="showVendorPage()">
                    <h5>Vendor</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col">.col</div>
                <div class="col">.col</div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: sometimes ng-click willnot work in cordova. Try using `onclick="showVendorPage()"`

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. I found the cause, because of which this thing is happening but, don't know how that whole thing is working.

What's happening is, Like home Controller I've one more controller for SIDEMENU (Menu.js). What I did, I copy that same function ```showVendorPage()``` in Menu.js Controller file. Then it's started working. No need to refresh the page. So, just after login ```showVendorPage()``` function working from Menu.js file & after refresh the page it's working from Home.js file. But, why this SCOPE is getting change like this that's I can't able to understand.